# What to say when you want someone to complete whatever they are doing and become available? "Get free" or "be free"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, sentence-meaning

So, I wanted to discuss something with my friend after he finished doing the dishes, so I said,

> **Get free** first, then we'll talk.

But now I think it is not correct and "be free first" would been better? What do you think would have been the right sentence in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Get free" is correct in your example sentence.

"Be free" doesn't make sense. It sounds like "*gain your freedom*", not "*become available*", which is what you intend.

Comment: Right. And if I rearrange it as "we'll talk after you are/get free", which one would be correct here?

Comment: @Frank They're both fine. It's the command "Be free" that has the idiomatic meaning of "gain your freedom". Otherwise it has the normal meaning of become available.